# How Can i use regex Flashtext python library

Tags: python, regex, keyword-search

I want to using Flashtext for find text

example code :

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()
# keyword_processor.add_keyword(<unclean name>, <standardised name>)
keyword_processor.add_keyword('Big Apple', 'New York')
keyword_processor.add_keyword('Bay Area')
keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords('I love Big Apple and Bay Area.')
keywords_found
['New York', 'Bay Area']
```

but I want to using regex in flashtext

example:

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()
# keyword_processor.add_keyword(<unclean name>, <standardised name>)
keyword_processor.add_keyword('\w{1,10}.txt')
keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords('Hello test.txt')
keywords_found
['test.txt']
```

How can i do this?

Comment: As of now flashtext does not support regex.

Comment: that's too bad :( Thank you for the reply